# What causes an error message like "internal error: failed to find embedded files of..." in go?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have been working on my branch for a couple of days. Meanwhile the `master` branch has evolved, so I do `git rebase master`.

The output shows CONFLICTs in some files:

```
Auto-merging vendor/modules.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in vendor/modules.txt
Auto-merging go.sum
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in go.sum
Auto-merging go.mod
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in go.mod
error: could not apply 1bd673ea... update vendor folder
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
update vendor folder
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 1bd673ea... update vendor folder
```

After fixing the conflicts, I do `go mod tidy` and then `go mod vendor`. The result is a strange message:

> internal error: failed to find embedded files of github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime: //go:build comment without // +build comment

What does this mean and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

From the final error message `//go:build comment without // +build comment`, it looks one of the tools is expecting both the new `//go:build` and the old `// +build` build constraint styles. My guess is this is because your `go.mod` says you want to support a version of Go older than 1.18 (when `// +build` became obsolete) but this `grpc-gateway` package is written for Go 1.18 and only includes a `//go:build` style constraint.

Looking at the source of the [file in question](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/1a287666fa2bc269ee0b81924244b2919fc335bd/runtime/query_fuzz_test.go), it looks like it does only have a `//go:build` comment, but the `go.mod` says it should support Go 1.17. So it seems like that package is broken... in fact, looks like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/2713) related to that. So you'll probably have to wait for them to fix it, use an older version that works, or use a `replace` in your own `go.mod` to use a fork.

I think this was broken a few days ago with the release of [v2.10.2](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/compare/v2.10.1...v2.10.2), when that fuzz file was added with the `//go:build` line and no `// +build` one.

**Update:** looks like this has been fixed in [v2.10.3](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/releases/tag/v2.10.3).